# Equality constraints represented as LMIs

Tags: semidefinite-programming, linear-matrix-inequality

I have three complex variables

$$x=\begin{bmatrix} x_1 & x_2 & x_3 \end{bmatrix}'$$

two complex knowns

$$d=\begin{bmatrix} d_1 & d_2 \end{bmatrix}'$$

and two equality constraints

$$x_1x_2 = d_1$$

$$x_1x_3 = d_2$$

I would like to know how to represent the equality constraints in linear matrix inequality (LMI) form so that I can use an SDP solver.

P.S. This is my first time posting a question, so tips on refining the question itself are also appreciated.

Comment: It would help make the question more self-contained if you gave a definition of what LMI form looks like.  People experienced with SDP would probably know this already, but this opens up the question to a wider audience and I suspect it will not be too hard for someone to figure out given the definition.

Comment: Your equality constraints do *not* define convex sets. However, LMIs do define convex sets.

Comment: @D.Park I must admit I assumed that when you said "equality constraints" that the constraints would be linear... If you could represent arbitrary non-linear equalities then you could also represent arbitrary non-linear constraints, which is unreasonable.